# Warning: Illegal string offset 'OperationRequest' in: Error in json / PHP

Tags: php, json, string

I have an array something like this

```
 {"OperationRequest":{"RequestId":"5b7ebeb4-2216-407b-8c01-3040d9291621",
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

I am using this PHP code to display data

```
echo $prTitle = $json['OperationRequest']['RequestIds'];
```

but it is display warning message

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'OperationRequest' in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder/file.php on line 46
```

Comment: $json->OperationRequest->RequestId?  You're using **RequestIds**, not **RequestId**.  Also, it would help if you posted more code.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution with the help of above comments post by "[user2182349](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2182349/user2182349)"

I use this code `$json->OperationRequest->RequestId` instead of `$json['OperationRequest']['RequestIds']` now its working fine.